# TikZ Matrix overwrite every column/row style for specific column/row

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-matrix

I tried to typeset a table like figure using TikZ matrix library and wanted to add stripes to it.
However I also wanted to style the last column and row in another color. Regardless of order and combinations of `.append style` `.prefix style` and normal `.style` I have not been able to overwrite the stripe color from `every odd row`.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=.75cm},
  every odd row/.style={nodes={fill=yellow!10}},
  column 6/.style={column sep=5pt},
  column 7/.style={nodes={fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}},
  row 5/.style={row sep=5pt},
  row 6/.style={nodes={fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}}
] {
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And an image of what it currently looks like:
[image: image showing the stripes overwriting the background color of the last column]

Comment: With regards to https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/867, I added a style that changes the order when invoked. Please use with care if you use it. Perhaps a feature request to implement something along these lines will be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "overwriting" is a consequence of the following excerpt of `tikz.code.tex`:

```
\def\tikz@common@matrix@code{%
  \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
  \tikzset{every cell/.try={\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
  \tikzset{column \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/.try}%
  \ifodd\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn%
    \tikzset{every odd column/.try}%
  \else%
    \tikzset{every even column/.try}%
  \fi%
  \tikzset{row \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow/.try}%
  \ifodd\pgfmatrixcurrentrow%
    \tikzset{every odd row/.try}%
  \else%
    \tikzset{every even row/.try}%
  \fi%
  \tikzset{row \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\space column \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/.try}%
  \tikz@options%
}%
```

As you can see, it goes through the column and row options in a certain order. In particular, it looks at the rows *after* the columns. So, as you say, the styles for the column will in general be overwritten by the styles for rows.

However, this problem is far from being unsolvable. Rather, I find it in most situations most convenient to directly work with the the counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow`. This allows one to implement whatever rule you like. In your case, your goal can be achieved with some code that computes an integer labeling the cases,

```
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(%
    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn==7||\pgfmatrixcurrentrow==6,0,%
     ifthenelse(isodd(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow),1,2))}
```

and then using `\ifcase`,

```
\ifcase\itest
\tikzset{fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}%
\or
\tikzset{fill=yellow!10}%
\or
\fi
```

This method is very powerful as you can implement more general conditions like a modulo condition, or more general functions of the row and column indices.

Here is the full code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{cond/.code={%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(%
    \pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn==7||\pgfmatrixcurrentrow==6,0,%
     ifthenelse(isodd(\pgfmatrixcurrentrow),1,2))}
%\typeout{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->\itest}  
\ifcase\itest
\tikzset{fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}%
\or
\tikzset{fill=yellow!10}%
\or
\fi
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=.75cm,cond},
  column 6/.style={column sep=5pt},
  row 5/.style={row sep=5pt},
] {
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**: With regards to [this issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/867), you could also install some reordering of the styles.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{reorder matrix styles/.style={execute at begin matrix={
\def\tikz@common@matrix@code{%
  \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
  \let\tikz@mode=\pgfutil@empty%
  \tikzset{every cell/.try={\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow}{\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn}}%
  \ifodd\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn%
    \tikzset{every odd column/.try}%
  \else%
    \tikzset{every even column/.try}%
  \fi%
  \ifodd\pgfmatrixcurrentrow%
    \tikzset{every odd row/.try}%
  \else%
    \tikzset{every even row/.try}%
  \fi%
  \tikzset{column \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/.try}%
  \tikzset{row \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow/.try}%
  \tikzset{row \the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow\space column \the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn/.try}%
  \tikz@options%
}%
}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[reorder matrix styles]
\matrix [
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={draw, anchor=center, minimum size=.75cm},
  every odd row/.style={nodes={fill=yellow!10}},
  column 6/.style={column sep=5pt},
  column 7/.style={nodes={fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}},
  row 5/.style={row sep=5pt},
  row 6/.style={nodes={fill=green!10, font=\bfseries}}
] {
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the same output as above. Note, however, that this is a bit of a hack, and one can think of scenarios in which this crashes.

Comment: I've implemented something to configure the order: https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/65bcaafffbd0b21974b085504b4853684d5ed8bc

Comment: @HenriMenke I prefer the first method of the answer. It allows one to implement mod 3 conditions, say, to play with `beamer` overlays (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546217/194703)), automatically label matrix entries, and much much more. I personally would find it much more useful if one added a wrapper for those to the matrix library. (There are many more additions to the matrix library possible, such as an alignment. One can use `eqparbox` but I feel this could be part of the library.)

Comment: @HenriMenke The main headache I have with the reordering is that you stack styles. In the case at hand, this is fine, you overwrite `fill=yellow!10` by `fill=green!10`. However, if you had something like `fill=yellow!10,text width=3em` and then a style for column 7 like `fill=green!10` you'd keep the `text width`. This may or may not be what the user wants, but with just reordering it is IMHO much harder to get what you like in general. That's why I do like `\ifcase`, which does *not* stack styles.

Comment: In the new key `matrix/inner style order` you can also install your own styles and even leave out existing ones, which will then not be considered at all.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, these styles are certainly nice. However, I think one could add a lot of value to the `matrix` library by just adding a bit more information to the manual. (I'll be happy to make a concrete proposal.) And even more value by adding some very simple styles, which could e.g. allow the user to add grid lines, and/or left- and right-align the cells.

Comment: Sure, just make sure to not change any defaults.  If possible, please add it to `tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex`.  Unfortunately, lots of matrix stuff is in `tikz.code.tex` where it really does not belong.

Comment: @HenriMenke OK, I will give it a try, The thing is that, as you probably know, you do not need to load the `matrix` library to use a matrix, but if you are saying that some stuff from `tikz.code.tex` could be moved to the pgf module `matrix`, then this is something one can think about (but IMHO there is a reason why it is in `tikz.code.tex`). Most of the relevant stuff is actually discussed **20 Matrices and Alignment**, a section that is not linked to (as far as I can see) in section **60 Matrix Library**, so I can see how this is confusing for users.

Comment: I think the fact that matrix code is in `tikz.code.tex` is mostly historical, but it can't be moved nowadays because it would break people's documents.  Note that most of the supplementary styles such as `matrix of nodes` are located in the `matrix` library, where all new supplementary stuff should go as well.  Just send me the updated files by email.

Comment: Also have you seen that I fixed https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/861?  Although I didn't do it in the way you proposed.  Running `\pgfmathparse` at a point where we already know that the input is a number is a bit too wasteful.  It also works with other functions than `reciprocal`: https://github.com/hmenke/pgf/commit/494bd677709b9f2eb938d96eeb0c2ad29ae37aa3

Comment: @HenriMenke I'll look at it at the weekend. I did extensive tests with `use fpu reciprocal`, and it always passed the tests.

Comment: @schrödinger I actually expect styles to stack (at least when using append/prepend) though I have not used tikz for too long and am not yet used to all the architectural concepts

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, just for curiosity: Did you see my email from Monday? It would be nice if you could shortly answer to that so I know if I can update the main repo too. Thanks.